# What is the significance of i in new RegExp(filter, "i")) when sorting in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using javascript to sort some  and I'm trying to figure out exactly what each line of code does so I can fix it to work how I'd like.

I'm just wondering what the siginificance of `i`  is in

```
(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0
```

I know that filter is the name I've given my sorting variable.

Comment: Three answers before your snarky comment... Really necessary?

Comment: Ok, considering it's just one character and a common vowel it's easy to miss on a documentation page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the case-insensitve flag. "g" is the global flag. you can use one or the other or both or none... "i" or "g" or "gi"

Answer (score 1):

"i" is the flag of regular expression which means ignore case

for example:

`new RegExp("abc", "i")` will generate regular expression `/abc/i`

`new RegExp("abc"`) will generate regular expression `/abc/`

a hint, if you could literally buid your regular expression, you could directly declare the expression such as: `var regexp = /abc/i`; if you need build it with composing the parts, you could use function constructor as your example

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
var reg = /...../i;
```

to achieve the same effect.

Comment: no he cant, because he is using a variable for the actual expression